# How do I start a Fuseki server from Jena API Eclipse project?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, fuseki

Hi I am new to the Semantic Web domain and Apache Jena enviroments too, which is why I am posting this question.

I have a project that makes use of Jena API. And when I run it, it shows output in the console.

I did run Fuseki server from cmd line and it ran as a local server and I could do some playing around with queries and all that.

My question is, is it possible to run the project on the server through my project that makes use of the API, and if so, why it should be done? I am confused as to the reason why we have a Fuseki server but aren't starting it through the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any java program with command line execution, you can call `main` directly:

```
org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiCmd.main("--loc=DB", "--update", "/ds") ;
```

This can be in a forked thread if you want.